# Configuring maven build profile

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm trying to configure a maven build profile, my purpose is to add the following dependencies everytime the is doesn't match some_id.

for some reason this does not work, I suspect that using the `! logical operator` does not work with id's. any ideas ?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>!some_id</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.project.apps</groupId>
                <artifactId>apps-cf</artifactId>
                <version>${apps.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.project.apps</groupId>
                <artifactId>apps-core</artifactId>
                <version>${apps.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Do not use profiles for different dependencies. Better make different modules which have the different dependencies...it's hard to maintain and you produce the same artifact which contains different transitive dependencies which no one can follow...

Comment: I have some modules which are in common, but have some dependencies that depend on the build profile. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more in detail how it looks like....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I guess you are looking for profile activation.

Have a look here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

you might want to go with the property approach.

Answer (score 0):

For the activation part, you want to do something like this:

```
<profile>
  <id>my_id</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>!some_property</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  ...
</profile>
```

However, as mentioned in some comments, you might be interested in scope for your dependencies. For example, only when compiling (provided). See for more details: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope